# cloudflare showing original ip of sub-domain or if you type anything like asdlasd.domain.com

Tags: cloudflare

I have a domain, when you open my domain it redirects to https:// which is fine but when you type anything like  alsdkalsdsda.domain.com it does not redirect to https:// and the MAIN problem when search for my domain original ip, you can find it by just typing anything of  subdomain. (rtwrwrwerwq.domain.com)

any solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you likely have a wildcard record --> * in place, which CloudFlare does not proxy unless you're using the enterprise level plan.  I'd encourage you to open a support ticket with CloudFlare's support team though so they can review your specific account settings further.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply,  Do you know to how to remove willcard record from linux ubuntu via ssh command. Thanks again

Comment: @Hsb you'd want to remove the wildcard at CloudFlare, not on the server directly. I would recommend contacting CloudFlare's support team if you need help with that.

Comment: Thank you very much. All sorted